# Get TimeSpan from HH:mm:ss string

Tags: c#, timespan, memorycache

I'm trying to get a `TimeSpan` from `"24:30:00"` string so I can define cacheOptions in C# but I'm getting 24 days instead of 24 hours.

```
string cacheExpirationTime = "24:00:00";
var cacheOptions = new MemoryCacheOptions()
{
    ExpirationScanFrequency = TimeSpan.Parse(cacheExpirationTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
};
```

I also tried without using `CultureInfo`, but it didn't work.

Which is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

24 hours is 1 day, so you should format it as such.

```
string cacheExpirationTime = "1.00:00:00";
var cacheOptions = new MemoryCacheOptions()
{
    ExpirationScanFrequency = TimeSpan.Parse(cacheExpirationTime, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
};
```

Comment: Seems like sending 24:00:00 throws an overflow exception, so I changed to 12 instead.

Comment: @Aritzbn, you're right, edited my example to remove the custom format. Just use the first example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the format **hh:mm:ss**. You need to specify the format, here "**hh:mm:ss**" is used. hh is for hours, mm for minutes, and ss for seconds.

Be aware that **24:00:00** could not be used because it's not a valid value for a **TimeSpan** object. The largest possible value for a **TimeSpan** object is **23:59:59**, so any value greater than that will cause an **OverflowException** to be thrown.

```
string cacheExpirationTime = "23:59:59";
string format = "hh\\:mm\\:ss";

var cacheOptions = new MemoryCacheOptions()
{
    ExpirationScanFrequency = TimeSpan.ParseExact(cacheExpirationTime, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
};
```

Comment: The necessity of escaping the colon with back slashes in the TimeSpan format string, as opposed to DateTime format string, is really a design flaw in .NET.

Comment: This code throws an `OverflowException`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `TimeStamp` assumes the input string represents a time duration in the format `days.hours:minutes:seconds` so you need to use a custom format string with `TimeSpan.ParseExact()` method like this:

```
string cacheExpirationTime = "24:00:00";
var cacheOptions = new MemoryCacheOptions()
{
    ExpirationScanFrequency = TimeSpan.ParseExact(cacheExpirationTime, @"h\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
};
```

Comment: This code throws an `OverflowException`.